# Is there any known lower bound for the number of polynomia functions over a finite field with fixed number of variables?

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, field-theory

Say we have a finite field $K$ of size $q$, is there an easy lower bound for the number of distinct polynomial functions in $K[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$? What about if we specifically fix the degree $d$, so that we only count those polynomial functions of degree $d$ on $n$ variables?

Comment: Hint: the space of polynomials over a field $K$ of a fixed degree $d$ is a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space, and a basis is given by monomials of degree $d$. Computing the number of monomials of a given degree is a purely combinatorial problem: it's the number of ways to choose $d$ elements (possibly with repetition) from a set of $n$ elements. It's a standard exercise in combinatorics to express this as either a multiset coefficient or a binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 2):

The total number of distinct polynomial functions is $q^{q^n}$, also equal to the total number of functions $f:K^n\to K$ (proof at end). Every such polynomial is equivalent to one where all variables have degree less than $q$, because of the identity $x^q=x$. As long as we restrict our attention to polynomials with this degree bound, then two polynomials represent the same function if and only if they have the same coefficients; indeed, there are $q^{q^n}$ polynomials where every variable has degree at most $q$, and these represent all functions, so they must all be distinct functions. Therefore, you can count polynomials of degree $d$ by counting the number of representations with degree $d$.

Let $m(n,q,d)$ be the number of monomials with degree at most $d$ where all powers of all variables are at most $q$. Then the number of polynomials of degree exactly $d$ is
$$
q^{m(n,q,d)}-q^{m(n,q,d-1)}
$$
Furthermore, $m(n,q,d)$ is equal to the number of nonnegative integers solutions to the equation $a_1+\dots+a_n\le d$. Using a standard stars-and-bars/inclusion-exclusion argument, we can show
$$
m(n,q,d)=\sum_{k\ge 0}(-1)^k\binom{n}k\binom{n+d-qk}{d-qk}
$$

---

*Proof*: To prove there are $q^{q^n}$ polynomial functions, you need to show every function can be represented as a polynomial, which we do now. First, given any vector $v=(v_1,\dots,v_n)\in K^n$, we will make a polynomial $p_v(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ whose value is $1$ when $(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(v_1,\dots,v_n)$, and zero otherwise. Then, any arbitrary function can be made using a linear combination of such polynomials. To do this, for each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, let
$$
g_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\prod_{a\in K\setminus \{v_i\}}\frac{x_i-a}{v_i-a}
$$
Note that $g_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is $1$ when $x_i=v_i$, and zero otherwise. Therefore, the desired polynomial is
$$
p_v(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^ng_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)
$$

Comment: Great, thank you! You might want to use a variable other than q in your definition of g_i though, because it's a bit confusing with the other use of q in the proof.

Comment: @FelipeSantos Good point, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The number of polynomials of at least degree $d$ is the number of homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ with $n$ variables.

There are ${n+d\choose n}$ monomials of degree $d$, so the number of polynomials at most degree $d$ with $n$ variables is $$q^{n+d\choose n}$$

Comment: How do we know that these are distinct though? They are distinct in their description, but how do we know that for any two of those polynomials f and g there is some x such that f(x) is not equal to g(x)?

Comment: Two polynomials are equal only if they have the same coefficients. You are thinking of polynomial *functions* which are different. @FelipeSantos

Comment: Equality of polynomials means equality of their coefficients, not equality as functions on the base field. For infinite fields, one can prove that these coincide, but for finite fields, they do not—for instance, in the finite field with $q$ elements, the function given by the polynomial $x^q - x$ is the zero function, but $x^q - x$ is not the zero polynomial.

Comment: Yes I am thinking about polynomial functions, perhaps more concisely even I am looking for a lower bound on the number of the largest set of polynomial functions of degree d that have a unique set of roots.

Comment: @FelipeSantos Then you ought to edit your question to specify that.

Comment: The number of monomials in $n+1$ variables with degree $d$ is $\binom{n+d}{n}$. Furthermore, $q^{\binom{n+d}{n}}$ counts polynomials with degree _at most_ $d$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Yea, calculation error on my part. I'll edit.